# Is android debug.keystore file valid for 30 years

Tags: android, key-storage

I am new to android.Now i am trying to understanding signing apk file. I created one app and signed with self signed certificate(with private keystore file) and every thing is fine. While i am trying to know more about **debug.keystore** ,i tried to sign apk with debug.keystore file when exporting apk in Eclips IDE. at the last step i observed that **Certificate expires on Fri Sep 19 15:02:42 IST 2042.** .
But the file **created on 26th Sep 2012**. When i goggling observed that **debug.keystore expired in 365 days**. But my debug.keystore showing 30 years.Is it possible. I am confused.
Can any one help me ,please clear my doubt.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No... that is only for 1 year (365 days)

Comment: Thank you, Pankaj Kumar. but when i am trying to use debug key insted of self signed keystore file to export signed apk in Eclips IDE it showing 30 years expire date.I know its not recommended to use debug key. but i am interested to know more about key store file.

Comment: You're probably confusing the **debug** keystore with the **release** keystore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no predetermined limit for expiration of certificates. Granted, most certificated issued by certification authorities are only valid for 1 year (365 days), but it does not have to be the case. Most certification authorities have expiration dates for their own CA certificates that are valid for 25 and more years.

If you are using self-signed certificate (which can be created using keytool or openssl), you can specify pretty much any expiration time. If we are talking about android debug.keystore, it most likely has some self-signed certificates which may default to 1 year expiration.

What you have seen (expiration in 2042) was most likely Android Test CA certificate.

Comment: Thank you mvp,I got it.I don't know what is Android Test CA certificate.please tell me about it.

Comment: keystore can contain both end certificates and CA (certificate authority) certificates. Usual certificate authorities like Verisign use their CA certificates to sign your end certificate and charge money for this service. Android Test CA certificate permits you to sign certificates with test key, which of course is not to be trusted by anybody, but it is good enough to test if you have basic signing working. When and if you want to have real certificates, you will have to pay money to real CA to get trusted certificate signed.

Comment: CA(certificate authority) certificate service is provided by some authorized organisation and we need to pay for that certificate,Right ! My debug keystore file have expiry date 30 years instead of 1 year. whats the reason. Is it SDK or IDE dependent.

Comment: debug.keystore is simply provided by Android with default test CA certificate preloaded. You can create your own test CA if you want, but it is easier to use this default. You can read more at http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#debugmode

Answer (score 2):

Best to generate your own debug key that does not expire in one year and use that, otherwise you will have troubles updating your apps later.

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android -keyalg RSA -validity 14000
```

Comment: Thank you tsukimi, yes, i created keystore file using keytool.exe. But i tested with debug key to know about signing process. my doubt is if  debug key expires in 365 days, eclips is showing 30 years to expire. why?

Answer (score 1):

See the things

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -alias aliasname -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Here the validity is 10000. So in that case it is not expire in 365 day.

Comment: Thank you sunil for your reply ,but Google saying debug file will expire in 365 days but why it showing 40 years.Is any thing wrong in my IDE.Can u tell me how to know the expire date of the keystore file. Instead of seeing created date, is there any commend.